# AFNetworking version 3 content-type error

Tags: ios, asp.net, json, wcf, afnetworking-3

I'm making an iphone app that will interact with a particular ASP.NET server. I've got the following code to register:

```
- (void)post:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(id))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure {
    path = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"path: %@, %@", path, parameters);
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

    [manager POST:path parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [myDelegate StopIndicator];
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [myDelegate StopIndicator];
         failure(error);
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
    }];

 }




//Register

-(void)registerUser:(NSString *)usertype firstname:(NSString *)firstname middlename:(NSString *)middlename lastname:(NSString *)lastname registration:(NSString *)registration password:(NSString *)password confirmpass:(NSString *)confirmpass email:(NSString *)email mobile:(NSString *)mobile success:(void (^)(id))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
    {
        NSDictionary *requestDict = @{@"UserTypeId" : usertype, @"FirstName" : firstname, @"MiddleName" : middlename,@"LastName" : lastname, @"RegNumber" : registration ,@"Password": password,@"ConfirmPassword" : confirmpass, @"EmailAddress" : email, @"MobileNumber" : mobile};

        [self post:kUrlSignup parameters:requestDict success:^(id responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"registerWithEmail: %@", responseObject);
            responseObject=(NSMutableDictionary *)[NullValueChecker checkDictionaryForNullValue:[responseObject mutableCopy]];
            if([self isStatusOK:responseObject])
            {
                success(responseObject);
            } else
            {
                [myDelegate StopIndicator];
                failure(nil);
            }
        } failure:^(NSError *error)
         {
             [myDelegate StopIndicator];

             failure(error);
         }];

    }
```

But it's giving me the following error having to do with Content-Type:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7c14e5c0> { URL: http://192.168.0.129/IISService/Service.svc/Registration } { status code: 415, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Mon, 01 Aug 2016 05:38:44 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.129/IISService/Service.svc/Registration, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>}
```

I am not sure if this error is from server side or I am making some mistake. How can I fix this error ?

Comment: @imjaydeep - This solution didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` support deal with response of request which `Content-Type` equal either of `application/json`,`text/json`,`text/javascript`. If your server return a response which `Content-Type` equal `text/html` or other, the `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` will not deal with your response and throw a error. You can add accept types by youself as below:

```
AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSMutableSet *acceptTypes = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:serializer.acceptableContentTypes];
[acceptTypes addObject:@"your-content-type"];
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = acceptTypes;
manager.responseSerializer = serializer;
```

Comment: I have already set the content-type and server is sending application/json.

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username":username, @"password":password};
[manager POST:@"URL Here" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This does the creation of the request, setting its Content-Type according to the requestSerializer setting, and encodes the JSON for you.

**Update 1:-**

```
+(void)callWebServicePOST_withAPIName:(NSString *)url withParameters:(id)parameters withBlock:(ResponseCompilationBlock)_Block {
    [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] setTimeoutInterval:60];
    [[AFHTTPSessionManager manager].requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

    [[AFHTTPSessionManager manager] POST:url parameters:parameters progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog (@"response:%@", responseObject);
        _Block (YES, 200, responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
        _Block (NO, 400, error);
    }];
}
```

Declare this method in AppDelegate file and call it just like this:-

```
[Appdelegate callWebServicePOST_withAPIName:@"url string" withParameters:params withBlock:^(BOOL isSuccess, NSInteger statusCode, id response) {
    if (isSuccess) {
       /* Do further procedure here */
    }
    else {
       NSLog (@"%@", [error localizedDescription])
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using afnetworking 3 and AFHTTPRequestOperation has been removed in that.

Comment: I have updated my answer from AFHTTPRequestOperation to AFHTTPSessionManager. Please try this. I am also using AFNetworking 3.x for my apps and I hope this will help you.

Comment: You have to make changes in "registerUser" this method.. Make request dictionary and change the code from [self post:] with the posted one.

Comment: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(AFHTTPSessionManager *__strong, __strong id)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nullable)(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull __strong, id  _Nullable __strong) - this is the error

Comment: Please follow my update 1 code. It'll surely work for you.

Comment: NB: Do not apply any kind of encoding as AFNetworking will automatically encode your JSON object.

Comment: I am not uploading any image. and also I have created web service file .h and .m and calling the web service on register button click. In that case what changes I need to make. Can you please check the whole code. I can email.

Comment: ok.. you can email the iOS code. I'll look into it and get back to you. send me code on nirmitdagly@hotmail.com